# Bookmark Plus: Correct bookmark file after directory/file rename

Tags: bookmarks

I had a couple of bookmarks for a given file, then I decided to rename the directory of the file. Now `list-bookmarks` ( I am using the `bookmark+` package) shows all the bookmarks for the given file in yellow (indicating that they are no longer valid).

How can I easily repair the bookmark file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The location (file) of a bookmark is in literal (string) form in the bookmark data, which is in variable `bookmark-list` and which is saved in your bookmark file.

You have these options, to change the file name of one or more bookmarks:

- You can use command `bmkp-edit-bookmark-name-and-location`, which is bound to **`C-x p r`** globally.  (A similar command is bound to **`r`** in the bookmark-list display.)  With no prefix arg you are prompted for a new bookmark name (just hit `RET` for the same name) and a new bookmark location (file).  With a prefix arg an editing buffer opens for the full bookmark record (what you see in the bookmark file).
- You can use command `bmkp-edit-bookmark-record`, which is bound to **`C-x p E`** globally.  (A similar command is bound to **`e`** in the bookmark-list display.)  This is like `C-u C-x p r`: An editing buffer opens for the full bookmark record.
- In the bookmark-list display (buffer `*Bookmark List*`), you can use command `bmkp-bmenu-relocate-marked`, which is bound to **`M-R`**.  It relocates the target files of all (visible) bookmarks that are marked `>`.
  You are prompted for the relocation target directory.  Omitted bookmarks are excluded, by default (so you can hide some bookmarks from this operation without unmarking them).  With a prefix arg, any omitted bookmarks that are marked are included.
- In the bookmark-list display (buffer `*Bookmark List*`), you can use command `bmkp-bmenu-edit-marked`, which is bound to **`E`**, to edit the full bookmark records of the bookmarks that are marked `>`.  An editing buffer opens for all of the full bookmark records together.  Omitted bookmarks are excluded, by default.  With a negative prefix arg, any omitted bookmarks that are marked are included.  With a non-negative prefix arg, the edit buffer includes *all* bookmarks.
- You can open your bookmark file as any file, and edit the text.  You can use `query-replace` etc.  However, it is probably a better idea to use `C-u E` in the bookmark list -- see previous (but be aware that `C-u E` works with the current `bookmark-list`, not the bookmark file, which is the last-saved `bookmark-list`).

There might be other possibilities, that I'm not thinking of at the moment. Use `C-h m` in the bookmark-list display for more information.  Or check the **`Bookmark+`** menu in the bookmark-list display.  Or check the **`Bookmarks`** menu anywhere (under `Edit` in vanilla Emacs).  Or use `apropos-command`...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily without using `bookmark+`

To upload a series of files in bulk, simply open the bookmark file (Typically `~/.emacs/emacs.bmk`) and do a `query-replace` where you search for the old path and replace it with the new one.